# Django ModelFormSet executes a single-object SELECT query per formset instance when validating (ORM inefficiency)

Tags: django, orm, django-forms, formset

**Conceptual summary of the issue:**

- Let's say we have a Django app with `Author` and `Book` models, and use a `BookFormSet` to add / modify / delete books that belong to a given `Author`.
- The problem is when the `BookFormSet` is validated, `ModelChoiceField.to_python()` ends up calling `self.queryset.get(id=123)` which results in a single-object SELECT query for **each** book in the formset.
- That means if I want to update 15 books, Django performs 15 separate SELECT queries, which seems incredibly inefficient. (Our actual app is an editor that can update any number of objects in a single formset, e.g. 50+).

**Here are a few things I tried:**

- First I tried passing a queryset to the `BookFormSet`, i.e. `formset = BookFormSet(data=request.POST, queryset=Book.objects.filter(author=1))`, but the `ModelChoiceField` still does its single-object SELECT queries.
- Then I tried to see where the `ModelChoiceField` defines its queryset, which seems to be in `BaseModelFormSet.add_fields()`. I tried initiating the `ModelChoiceField` with the same queryset that I passed to the formset, e.g. `Book.objects.filter(author=1)` instead of the original code which would be `Book._default_manager.get_queryset()`. But this doesn't help because the new queryset I defined isn't actually linked to what was passed to the formset and previously evaluated. So the multiple SELECT queries still happen. (Note: I realize `model._default_manager.get_queryset()` might be necessary in cases where the formset can be used to switch one Model instance to another instance which might not be in the original queryset passed to the `BaseModelFormset`, but this is not our use case)
- I noticed that `BaseModelFormSet._existing_object()` actually provides a way to check whether an object exists in the queryset that was giving to the formset constructor, which means that queryset is evaluated at most once and the results stored in `BaseModelFormSet._object_dict`. I thought there might be some way to have `ModelChoiceField.to_python()` do a similar check before calling `self.queryset.get(id=123)`, but I don't think `ModelChoiceField` is aware of `BaseModelFormSet`, and it would seem an anti-pattern to reach up the hierarchy like this.

The easiest solution seems to me to pass `BaseModelFormSet._object_dict` in some way to each ModelForm that's created, and then allow the `ModelChoiceField` to check this `_object_dict` before making another SELECT query.

Appendix:

Here's a screenshot from Django-Debug-Toolbar showing the first SELECT query (which is the queryset passed to the BaseModelFormSet), followed by 4 separate SELECT queries (one for each form.instance)
[image]

Note: I've also posted this as a Django ticket here:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32244#comment:1

Even if this could be solved with some form of caching, it still seems inefficient application-layer logic.

Comment: Edit: I think this may be a deeper Django ORM issue in that if you have `qs = Book.objects.filter(author=1)` (let's say this gives back 3 Books with id = 1,2,3), and then evaluate it -- i.e. `len(list(qs))` -- and then try `book2 = qs.get(id=2)` this will still run a SELECT query even though book2 was already fetched when the original queryset was evaluated

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a very hacky workaround that preserves the formset functionality we need. Basically in `BookForm` you can override `ModelForm._clean_fields()`

```
def _clean_fields(self):
        # remove 'id' field so it's not cleaned 
        # (this is the ModelChoiceField that's generating an extra SELECT query per Book object in the formset during clean)
        id_field = self.fields.pop('id')

        # run normal cleaning, with the form now unaware of its own 'id' field
        super(BookForm, self)._clean_fields()

        # add 'id' field back and insert it into clean_data
        id_value = id_field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix('id'))
        self.cleaned_data['id'] = id_value

        # add the 'id' field back into the form
        self.fields['id'] = id_field
```